# Basic comparison of macro to string in lualatex?

Tags: luatex, conditionals

Still hammering away at a database problem. Mostly done, but stumped by:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\testmacro}{U01}

The macro testmacro equals ``U01''

\directlua{
if \testmacro == ("U01") then tex.print ("testmacro equals U01")
    elseif \testmacro == ("U02") then tex.print ("testmacro not equal")
else tex.print ("Nothing matched")end}

\end{document}
```

Output is:

> The macro testmacro equals ``U01''
>
> Nothing matched

I've got a similar thing using a counter working properly, so kind of mystified here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\directlua` does expansion, so you are doing

```
if U01 == ("U01")
```

that clearly returns false. You have to quote the string:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\testmacro}{U01}

\directlua{
if "\testmacro" == "U01" then tex.print ("testmacro equals U01")
    elseif "\testmacro" == "U02" then tex.print ("testmacro not equal")
else tex.print ("Nothing matched")end}

\renewcommand{\testmacro}{U02}

\directlua{
if "\testmacro" == "U01" then tex.print ("testmacro equals U01")
    elseif "\testmacro" == "U02" then tex.print ("testmacro not equal")
else tex.print ("Nothing matched")end}

\renewcommand{\testmacro}{U03}

\directlua{
if "\testmacro" == "U01" then tex.print ("testmacro equals U01")
    elseif "\testmacro" == "U02" then tex.print ("testmacro not equal")
else tex.print ("Nothing matched")end}

\end{document}
```

[image]